# Application hangs when calling printf to uart with bare metal raspberry pi

Tags: c, gcc, arm, raspberry-pi, bare-metal

I am trying to implement a bare metal application on the raspberry pi and want to hook up stdout to the mini uart for debugging purposes.

I have followed the process outlined [here](http://www.valvers.com/embedded-linux/raspberry-pi/step02-bare-metal-programming-in-c-pt2) and [here](http://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/12/16/using-newlib-in-arm-bare-metal-programs/)

I have created a uart_putc function which seems to work perfectly, allowing me to print messages to my PC's COM port.  I then implemented the _write syscall, making it call my uart_putc function for output.  This works fine if I pass a single string literal into printf additional literal parameters or any non-literal parameters nothing is printed to the serial port and after a few calls, the application hangs.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be going wrong?  Happy to provide further info if needed...

```
void uart_putc(char c)
{
    while(1)
    {
        if(aux[AUX_MU_LSR]&0x20) break;

        led_blink(); // Blink the LED off then on again to 
                     // make sure we aren't stuck in here
    }
    aux[AUX_MU_IO] = c;
}
```

...

```
int _write(int file, char* ptr, int len)
{
    int todo;

    for (todo = 0; todo < len; todo++) 
    {
        uart_putc(*ptr++);
    }
    return len;
}
```

...

```
while(1)
{
    printf("Hello World\r\n"); // Works
}

while(1)
{
    printf("Hello %s\r\n", "World"); // This doesn't print anything
                                     // and will hang after about five calls
}

char* s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100); // Heap or stack it doesn't matter
strcpy(s, "Hello World\r\n");
while(1)
{
    printf(s); // This doesn't print anything
               // and will hang after about five calls
}

while(1)
{
    for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) 
    {
        uart_putc(s[i]);  // Works
    }
}
```

**Update**

I am using newlib and _write works correctly when called directly.  snprintf seems to exhibit the same problem, i.e.

```
snprintf(s, 100, "hello world\r\n"); // Works
snprintf(s, 100, "hello %s\r\n", "world"); // Doesn't work
```

My implementation of _sbrk was nicked from the page referenced in my OP

```
char *heap_end = 0;
caddr_t _sbrk(int incr) {
    extern char heap_low; /* Defined by the linker */
    extern char heap_top; /* Defined by the linker */
    char *prev_heap_end;

    if (heap_end == 0)
    {
        heap_end = &heap_low;
    }
    prev_heap_end = heap_end;

    if (heap_end + incr > &heap_top)
    {
        /* Heap and stack collision */
        return (caddr_t)0;
    }

    heap_end += incr;
    return (caddr_t) prev_heap_end;
 }
```

Linker script

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littlearm", "elf32-bigarm",
          "elf32-littlearm")
OUTPUT_ARCH(arm)
ENTRY(_start)
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib");
SECTIONS
{
  /* Read-only sections, merged into text segment: */
  PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x8000)); . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x8000);
. = 0x8000;
 .ro : {
  *(.text.startup)
  *(.text)
  *(.rodata)
 }
 .rw : {
  *(.data)
  __bss_start__ = .;
  *(.bss)
  __bss_end__ = .;
  *(COMMON)
 }
 . = ALIGN(8);
 heap_low = .; /* for _sbrk */
 . = . + 0x10000; /* 64kB of heap memory */
 heap_top = .; /* for _sbrk */
 . = . + 0x10000; /* 64kB of stack memory */
 stack_top = .; /* for startup.s */
}
```

start.s

```
.section ".text.startup"

.global _start

_start:
    ldr sp, =stack_top

    // The c-startup
    b       _cstartup

_inf_loop:
    b       _inf_loop
```

**Update 2**

Further experiments involving snprintf:

```
snprintf(s, 100, "hello world\r\n"); // Works

snprintf(s, 100, "hello %s\r\n", "world"); // Doesn't work
snprintf(s, 100, "hello %d\r\n", 1); // Doesn't work

char s[100];
char t[100];

strcpy(s, "hello world\r\n");
snprintf(t, 100, s); // Doesn't work
```

Comment: Make sure you have header file with printf declaration included (stdio.h or whatever) or insert printf declaration implicitly (`int printf ( const char * format, ... );`).

Comment: Can you show us the declaration of the variable "aux"? Can you use a debugger and say exactly at which line it hangs?

Comment: I have included stdio.h. I can't debug it, I can only speculate by blinking the led or printing things to the serial port (poor man's debugging).  The aux declaration is just a pointer to the memory mapped location of the uart registers - volatile unsigned int* aux = (unsigned int*)0x20215000UL;

Comment: You should initialize the exception vector and uart_putc() the name of the exception or at least blink the LED at a different speed than normal. Something is probably throwing an exception and crashing.

Answer (score 3):

This does not look like a UART problem, but rather a library problem.

If you want to make sure my assumption is correct, call `_write()` directly and see, if it works. Most probably it will. Also, I assume you are using `newlib`.

If `_write()` works as expected, the problem is limited into the upper layers of `printf`. Unfortunately `printf` is like an onion, you have to peel it layer-by-layer, and it'll make you cry.

Just for fun, a snippet from the `newlib` source code:

```
/*
 * Actual printf innards.
 *
 * This code is large and complicated...
 */
```

Luckily, there are still some ways to debug the problem without getting lost into `vfprintf.c`. Maybe the easiest starting point is to try `snprintf()`, because it lacks the memory management problems. The memory allocation code includes things such as `sbrk` which may be one problem. One would be tempted to think that the memory management is ok, as `malloc()` seemingly works, but that is not always the case. (`malloc()` may look ok even if it gives wrong addresses, but memory corruption will happen.)

Let us know where you get with these debugging steps! (My educated guess is that `sbrk` does not work for some reason, and that wrecks memory management.)

---

**Update** As it seems that the problem is not in memory allocation -- at least not only in memory allocation -- we need to tackle the onion. I hope you are not wearing too heavy make-up... (This makes me cry, and I am not 100 % sure the analysis below is correct. So take it with a pinch of salt.)

What happens in `newlib` when `printf` is called? The story is in the `newlib` source in folder `newlib/libc/stidio`.

**Layer 1: `printf()`**

First, `printf.c`:

```
int
_DEFUN(printf, (fmt),
       const char *__restrict fmt _DOTS) 
{
  int ret;
  va_list ap;
  struct _reent *ptr = _REENT;

  _REENT_SMALL_CHECK_INIT (ptr);
  va_start (ap, fmt);
  ret = _vfprintf_r (ptr, _stdout_r (ptr), fmt, ap);
  va_end (ap);
  return ret;
}
```

Quite simple. If something is going wrong, it is either:

- `_REENT_SMALL_CHECK_INIT(ptr);` or
- handling of varargs

I don't think the re-entrancy is a problem here, so I would concentrate on the varargs. Maybe it would be a good idea to make a minimal varargs test code, which would then show if they are broken. (I do not see why they would be broken, but in an embedded system it is safer not to assume anything.)

**Layer 2: `_vfprintf_r()`**

This is an internal version of standard `vfprintf` (varargs-version of file-`printf`) with re-entrant code. It is defined in `vfprintf.c`. It comes in several flavours depending on which switches have been used during the library compilation: `STRING_ONLY` (no memory allocation) and/or `NO_FLOATING_POINT`. I'll assume you have the full version, in which case the correct function can be found under the name `_VFPRINTF_R` (some `#define`ing has been going on).

The code is not too easy to read, first few hundred lines of the function consist of declaring many variables (depending on the compile options) and a dozen or so macros. However, the first thing the function really does is an endless loop to scan the format string for `%`. When it finds a `\0` instead, it does `goto done;` (yeah, it's got `goto`s, as well -- I'd like to throw this to code review...)

However, this gives us a clue: if we do not put any extra arguments, we just jump to `done` where we have some cleanup. This we can survive, but not the handling of any format arguments. So, let us look at where `%s` would end up. This is done as one would expect, there is a big `switch(ch) ...`. At `s` it says:

```
    case 's':
        cp = GET_ARG (N, ap, char_ptr_t);
        sign = '\0';
        if (prec >= 0) {
            /*
             * can't use strlen; can only look for the
             * NUL in the first `prec' characters, and
             * strlen () will go further.
             */
            char *p = memchr (cp, 0, prec);

            if (p != NULL) {
                size = p - cp;
                if (size > prec)
                    size = prec;
            } else
                size = prec;
        } else
            size = strlen (cp);

        break;
```

(Now, I have assumed you do not have multibyte string support `MB_CAPABLE` switched on in your `newlib`. If you have, the thing just got much more complicated.) The rest looks easy to debug (`strlen` and `memchr`), but the `GET_ARG`macro may be complicated -- again depending on your compile settings (if you have `_NO_POS_ARGS`, it is much simpler).

After the switch, the simple case (no padding in the format string) is:

```
PRINT (cp, size);
```

which is the printing macro. At least if the pointer `cp` is wrong, then odd things will happen.

The macro itself cannot be horrendously crazy, as we can print the simple case; only the arguments cause problems.

I am afraid this is a bit sticky to debug, but the symptoms point at something getting corrupted in memory. One thing to check is the return value of your `printf`. It should return the number of characters printed. Whether or not the return value is sane helps debugging the rest.

Comment: +1 for `you have to peel it layer-by-layer, and it'll make you cry.`

Comment: @gareththegeek: Now that it really seems to be a `sbrk` problem, you might be best off opening a new question on that. That way the problems are more searchable and answers more useful in the future. Also, my expertise on debugging this is becoming thin, and opening a new question will attract more brainpower. (Whether or not you consider this question answered is up to you, no hard feelings if you leave it open.)

Comment: I initially stated that snprintf worked but I was mistaken, please re-read my update - snprintf doesn't work if I use %s etc.

Comment: So, it is back to the onion-peeling! While you say "%s etc.", do you mean you have tried the others, as well? Because if `%s` does not work but e.g `%d` works, then we have a new lead.

Comment: snprintf seems to behave exactly the same as printf, see update 2

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry I'm so late to solve this problem for you. I'm the author of the valvers.com bare metal tutorials. The cause of the crash is due to something I was aware of, but hadn't had time to solve. Actually, I didn't know it would be the solution to your problem.

In short, the problem is that we're telling the toolchain that the processor is an ARM1176 and more importantly that the floating point unit is VFP, and we should use the hard-float ABI.

Using the VFP is an important option - it means we pick up the C library that's also been compiled with this option. Generally the VFP instructions aren't used and therefore do not trip us up. Clearly, portions of printf do use VFP instructions.

The reason this trips us up is because the startup assembler which is responsible for generating a good C runtime environment doesn't enable VFP, so when you reach a VFP instruction the processor jumps to the undefined instruction exception vector.

This is how I found out that this was the problem. I simple enabled the LED in any of the exception vectors and it lit when using printf formatting. Then it was a case of removing the LED calls in the exception vectors until it didn't light anymore. This happened in the "Undefined Instruction" exception. A quick search on the ARM site reveals the processor will go here if a VFP instruction is encountered and the VFP is not enabled. Hence, it reminded me to sort that out!

**The Solution**

There are a few things you need to do. You need to replicate the CMAKE_C_FLAGS to CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS in the CMakeLists.txt file so that the correct options are passed to the assembler, currently they are not! I will update the tutorials as soon as possible to fix this!

Just below the last `set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS ... )` command in the CMakeLists.txt file add `set( CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} )` which works okay because CMake uses gcc as the assembler.

Next, we need to modify the startup assembler file (in my tutorials armc-nnn-start.S) to enable the VFP. Insert the code below just above `bl    _cstartup`

(This is directly off the [TI Website](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Cortex-A8#How_to_enable_NEON))

```
// Enable VFP/NEON
// r1 = Access Control Register
MRC p15, #0, r1, c1, c0, #2
// enable full access for p10,11
ORR r1, r1, #(0xf << 20)
// ccess Control Register = r1
MCR p15, #0, r1, c1, c0, #2
MOV r1, #0
// flush prefetch buffer because of FMXR below
MCR p15, #0, r1, c7, c5, #4
// and CP 10 & 11 were only just enabled
// Enable VFP itself
MOV r0,#0x40000000
// FPEXC = r0
FMXR FPEXC, r0
```

You can find some information from ARM about this [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0098a/index.html).

Those changes are enough to get printf formatting working okay (I've tested it on the UART). If you have any further problems, don't hesitate to ask.

Lastly, sorry you've had grief because the startup code is not correct! The last thing I'd want to do is cost someone's time!!

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer, unfortunately my raspberry pi seems to be dead at the moment!  I will give your solution a try once I get hold of a working pi.  Thanks for the excellent tutorials btw, they are very informative.