# Can't run simple printf on cortex a55

Tags: c, arm64, cortex-a

I'm trying to get started with the RK3568 controller (cortex a55)
I have a project and a makefile
I managed to output the character using registers and flashing the LED.
But if I try to output a string using printf, the program just freezes without any signs of life.
I was looking for a solution to the problem, and the main solution is to implement the `_write function(int file, char *ptr, int len)`, which the standard printf function should use. But it doesn't help.
I tried to connect another Printf function from github and it works. I don't understand what the reason is.
I tried to call other functions from the standard library, for example `strlen` and it has the same behavior as `printf`

```
int _write(int file, char *ptr, int len)
{
    __io_putchar('w');
    int DataIdx;

    for (DataIdx = 0; DataIdx < len; DataIdx++)
    {
        __io_putchar( *ptr++ );
    }
    return len;
}
```

I am using the AArch64 bare-metal target compiler ([aarch64-none-elf](https://developer.palm.com/downloads/-/gnu-a))
I tried using another AArch32 bare-metal target compiler ([arm-none-eabi](https://developer.palm.com/downloads/-/gnu-a)), but there are even more problems with it. He can't even build the project and throws assembler errors.

```
Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- `msr tpidr_el 1,xzr'
Error: ARM register expected -- `ldr x1,=_start'
```

and many more similar

my makefile, maybe its help

```
PWD := $(shell pwd)
PRJ_BUILD := $(PWD)/build
CC  := aarch64-none-elf-gcc
LD  := aarch64-none-elf-ld
OBJCOPY := aarch64-none-elf-objcopy
OBJDUMP := aarch64-none-elf-objdump

SRC := src/entry_point.S
SRC += src/cache.S
SRC += src/main.c
SRC += src/stub.c
SRC := $(addprefix $(PWD)/,$(SRC))

INCLUDES := .
INCLUDES += src
INCLUDES := $(addprefix -I$(PWD)/,$(INCLUDES))

CFLAGS := -c -g 
#CFLAGS += -march=armv8.2-a -mcpu=cortex-a55
CFLAGS += -mcpu=cortex-a55
#-mcpu=cortex-a55 -mfloat-abi=hard

define get_library_path
    $(shell dirname $(shell $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -print-file-name=$(1)))
endef
LDFLAGS += -L $(call get_library_path,libc.a)
LDFLAGS += -L $(call get_library_path,libgcc.a)
LDFLAGS += -T $(PWD)/link.lds -lgcc -lc


all: app.elf

app.elf:
    $(info $(PWD))
    $(info SRC:[$(SRC)])
    $(info INCLUDES:[$(INCLUDES)])
    cd $(PRJ_BUILD) && $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(SRC)
    cd $(PRJ_BUILD) && \
        $(LD) -o app.elf $(PRJ_BUILD)/*.o \
        $(LDFLAGS) -Map app.map
    cd $(PRJ_BUILD) && $(OBJCOPY) -O binary app.elf app.bin
    cd $(PRJ_BUILD) && $(OBJDUMP) app.elf -dS > app.lst

    
clean:
    cd $(PRJ_BUILD) && rm -f *.*
```

I would be glad to at least some advice

Comment: Welcome to SO. I am not familiar with that toolset but I would assume you provide wrong CPU settings in either the compiler or the assembler. You should show how you build your code.

Comment: CFLAGS := -c -g -mcpu=cortex-a55. I tried to look for a solution in this direction, but I didn't find it

Comment: Please add that information to the question, not in comment. Also this does not show how you build. Please show complete compilation/assembler/linker command lines. The command you show, only provides target information to the compiler, not the assembler

Comment: For which files do you get the error messages? For the `.S` files?

Comment: yes, If I use a second compiler (arm-none-eabi).

Comment: "implement the `_write function(int file, char *ptr, int len)`, which the standard printf function should use. But it doesn't help". Implementing `_write` is a right way to go. This function should write to SoC UART registers. What is your implementation ?

Comment: `Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- 'msr tpidr_el 1,xzr'` - you could not use 32bit ARM toolchain (arm-none-eabi) to build 64b code.

Comment: @user3124812
I am updating the source code. But I think it's the right execution. 
I tried to output a string (initialization was inside main) in a loop (for and while), but failed (everything freezes). If the string is declared as global (before main), then everything works. Now I think there might be something wrong with the stack. But I'm not sure, I don't have enough knowledge. Is it possible to somehow determine this programmatically?

Comment: "but failed (everything freezes)" what does that mean ? stop right after first `__io_putchar('w');` or after printing part of the string ? In latest case try `for (DataIdx = 0; DataIdx < len; DataIdx++) { __io_putchar('x'); }` to see if it could output such amount of symbols.

Comment: @user3124812 I'm sorry. The very first __io_putchar('w'); was added by me for debugging. Since only the symbol is output, I added a function call to understand whether the program is coming here or not. And I don't see anything being output. That is, the code doesn't even get there.

Comment: well, that's a good indicator that stack is likely be alright. It seems that `__io_putchar` implementation causing a problem. I'm guessing that it waits for some bits in UART registers. Instead of calling `__io_putchar` just write to UART registers directly. UART registers layout should be somewhere in RK3568 reference manual.

Comment: @user3124812 Do you think the implementation of '__io_putchar' is wrong? If I call this function just in the main function, it works fine. Then how does it cause an error inside another function? It sounds very strange.

Comment: Checked my Lst file. It is assumed that the Printf function does not even call my _write function. I don't understand this behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was able to solve this problem
I tried to do the following

1. I implemented the `_sbrk` function (get from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589235/application-hangs-when-calling-printf-to-uart-with-bare-metal-raspberry-pi))
2. I tried to highlight heap and stack
3. I implemented the `_write` function (but did not touch `_write_r` [!])
4. I provided the implementation of the `memcmp`, `memset`, `memmove`, `memcpy` functions
   In reality, item No. has the greatest impact on work.4. If you remove everything except point 4, then the code works and I can output "Hello world"!
   Let me remind you that I use `aarch64-none-elf-gcc`
   item 4 I took from here https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/03/22/memset-memcpy-memcmp-and-memmove/